# How to Check if sub category of parent have atleast one post?

Tags: php, wordpress

In the loop of single.php I want to check, If any of my sub category of parent have posts.
Basically i want to add different range against my each posts.
So in single.php i want to check if this category have range then first show all posts of that range,
Otherwise show detail of parent category.

Here is my Code.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );
    if($post_categories) {
        echo 'this post have range and i want to display all range of that posts (means sub category)';
    }else{
    ?>
    <div class="product">
    <div class="pro-image"> <?php the_post_thumbnail()?> </div>
         <div class="prod-content">
              <h1><?php the_title()?></h1>
         </div>
    </div>
    <?php }
    endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What if there are multiple parents?

Comment: @mevius thanks for your reply.
I have total 8 Parents, and each parent have separate posts.
in some cases parent have sub categories which i treat as a range of that post. Please let me know if it is not clear ?

Comment: @menium is it possible?